# When Yahoo Historical Quotes Gets Updated Daily

Tags: api, quotes, yahoo, finance

I have pulled down the historical quotes from yahoo finance and am trying to add the new quotes (today - weekday's quotes) to my database. However, I don't know I should schedule the pull down process to when. It should be some time at night but anyone has an idea when the new (today's) quotes available from yahoo finance API?

Update: I just found more info from: http://marketmonksmusings.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-yahoo-free-eod-data.html

It looks they are available from 12AM GMT, but it would be better to pull down again later for more precise quotes.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question, so, using a script I'd written to update the stock data, I wrote a sequence of commands to update AAPL data every minute for ten hours overnight and print the top two lines of the file containing historical data, i.e.

```
for i in {1..600}; do 
  ../updatedata.py aapl.csv
  head -n2 aapl.csv
  date
  sleep 60 
done
```

The relevant excerpt of the results was:

```
updating aapl.csv from 2016-01-21 to 2016-1-22
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-01-21,97.059998,97.879997,94.940002,96.300003,52054500,96.300003
Fri, Jan 22, 2016  8:12:06 PM
updating aapl.csv from 2016-01-21 to 2016-1-22
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-01-22,98.629997,101.459999,98.370003,101.419998,65562800,101.419998
Fri, Jan 22, 2016  8:13:07 PM
updating aapl.csv from 2016-01-22 to 2016-1-22
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-01-22,98.629997,101.459999,98.370003,101.419998,65562800,101.419998
Fri, Jan 22, 2016  8:14:08 PM
```

where times are EST. This particular stock was updated at 8:13 PM EST. I would assume it does take some time to update all the stock data, so perhaps retrieving the data at 9:00:00PM EST would be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

For stocks, I do it at 4:15pm ET. NYSE closes at 4:00pm but sometimes the final closing price does not become available on Yahoo until a few minutes later. To be (reasonably) sure I get the final quotes, I do at 15 minutes after the close.